# Can someone help me Convert Grammar to regular expresion

Tags: grammar, formal-languages

Can someone help me convert grammar to regular expression and explain how to do it on some complex grammars?

```
S -> aA | bB
A -> aC | bC | a | b
B -> aC | bC | a | b
C -> aA
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Context-free grammars can describe languages which are not regular, and so cannot be described by a regular expression. See also [pumping lemma.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma)

Comment: @tripleee if i correctly understand, i need to convert it to finite automate and if it accepted than i can write an regular expression?

Comment: @tripleee: [right-linear grammars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) are equivalent to regular expressions.

Comment: @ivanovici: yes, converting to a finite automaton is easy and that can then be transformed into a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grammar of yours:

```
S -> aA | bB
A -> aC | bC | a | b
B -> aC | bC | a | b
C -> aA
```

Happens to be a right-regular grammar. As such, it describes a regular language and can easily be converted to a deterministic finite automaton:

```
q    s    q'
S    a    A
S    b    B
A    a    (C)
A    b    (C)
B    a    (C)
B    b    (C)
(C)  a    A
(C)  b    [D]
[D]  a    [D]
[D]  b    [D]
```

Here, S is the initial state, C is accepting and D is dead. To get a regular expression, treat this automaton as a NFA and start replacing symbol labels with regular expressions eliminating states:

```
S = aA + bB
A = aC + bC + a + b
B = aC + bC + a + b
C = aA + bD
D = aD + bD
```

Notice that `D = aD + bD = (a + b)D` is only true if `D = {}`. Rewriting:

```
S = aA + bB
A = aC + bC + a + b
B = aC + bC + a + b
C = aA
```

Now we can safely eliminate `C` by substitution:

```
S = aA + bB
A = aaA + baA + a + b = (aa + ba)A + (a + b)
B = aaA + baA + a + b = (aa + ba)A + (a + b)
```

Now we can use the rule `Z = xZ + y => Z = x*y`:

```
S = aA + bB
A = (aa + ba)*(a + b)
B = aaA + baA + a + b = (aa + ba)A + (a + b)
```

Now substitute:

```
S = aA + bB
A = (aa + ba)*(a + b)
B = (aa + ba)(aa + ba)*(a + b) + (a + b)
```

Now again:

```
S = a(aa + ba)*(a + b) + b((aa + ba)(aa + ba)*(a + b) + (a + b))
```

Now we can group like terms:

```
S = (a(aa + bb)* + b(aa + ba)(aa + ba)* + b)(a + b)
```

Notice that `b(aa + ba)(aa + ba)* + b` can be factored `b((aa + ba)(aa + ba)* + e)` and that `(aa + ba)(aa + ba)* + e = (aa + ba)*`:

```
S = (a(aa + bb)* + b(aa + ba)*)(a + b)
```

We can factor again:

```
S = (a + b)(aa + ba)*(a + b)
```

This last expression is a good, concise, correct regular expression for your language. It basically encodes the idea "see one symbol, then see another symbol, but if you see a third symbol it had better not be a b".